# Woocommerce My Account Page Downloads

Tags: woocommerce, registration, woothemes

I'd like to set up the my-account page for all users to have several free downloads already available to them in woocommerce.   Any ideas as to how to just have that content available to users if they register for the site?  I see that such an availability is made on the woothemes.com site if you register.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "just have that content available", then upload your files anywhere, grab their URLs and add them to My Account page by editing template myaccount/my-account.php - format them as buttons or anchor elements and set href attribute to link to each of your files.